# Get DNS-Server, DHCP-Server, gateway etc by ip address

Tags: c#, dns

I'm writing a program in which the user can type in a URL and then gets some network information. I managed to get the ip address. For this I use this code:

```
IPAddress[] ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(txtURL.Text);
MessageBox.Show(ipAddress[0].ToString());
```

This works fine. Now I want to get the DNS-Server (for example) of this ip address. I just found some threads about getting the local DNS server but thats not what I need.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot get a remote system's DNS, DHCP servers with just their IP. You might be able to *guess* their gateway, but I'm not sure how useful any of this information is.

Comment: Ah okay, nice to know. If I'd have the gateway, it could be possible?

Comment: Knowing their gateway would not help you get the other information, no.